# Dropdown in UserControl: Event is not Raised

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a user control named “LettersDropControl“. It has a dropdown list. I am using this control in a aspx page. When I change the selected item  it is not calling the ddlLetters_SelectedIndexChanged event handler? What change I need to make in order to execute the code in ddlLetters_SelectedIndexChanged event handler?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LettersDropControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MSAJAX1.LettersDropControl" %>
```

```
    public partial class LettersDropControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

      private string selectedLetter;
      public string SelectedLetter
     {
        get { return selectedLetter; }
        set { selectedLetter = value; }
    }


    // Delegate 
    public delegate void OnButtonClick(string strValue);
    // Event 
    public event OnButtonClick btnHandler;


    protected void ddlLetters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("TEST");

        SelectedLetter = ddlLetters.SelectedItem.Value;
        // Raise event if there is a subscription
        if (btnHandler != null)
        {
            btnHandler(string.Empty);
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlLetters.Items.Add("A");
            ddlLetters.Items.Add("B");

        }
    }


}
```

The aspx page is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MSAJAX1.Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CP" TagName="LetterCtrl" Src="LettersDropControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
 <CP:LetterCtrl id="LetterCtrl1" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you set ddlLetters's AutoPostback="true" ? post you design code also.

Comment: yes also post your ascx control's markup that will help identify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in case you have added the `AutoPostBack` property for the concerned dropdown. something like this

`<asp:DropDownList 1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">`

Comment: I have edited your post since it was not formatted and added a bit of text. please modify/revert as required

Comment: @Lijo AutoPostBack is always needed. That's how the server side knows that there was a change in the DDL selected item.